# trying to make 2 motors to rotate at same time

Tags: arduino

im trying to make 2 motors to rotate at ones with the following skecth

```
#define MotorSpeed 7
#define MotorDirection 6
#define MotorSpeed2 5
#define MotorDirection2 4

void setup(){

 pinMode(MotorSpeed, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(MotorDirection, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(MotorSpeed2, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(MotorDirection2, OUTPUT);

 Serial.begin(9600);         
}    


void loop() {

 for(int motorValue = 0 ; motorValue <= 255; motorValue +=10){
 analogWrite(MotorSpeed, motorValue); 
 delay(100);      
 }

 {
 analogWrite(MotorSpeed, 255);
 delay(1000);
 }

 {
 for(int motorValue = 255 ; motorValue >= 0; motorValue -=10){
 analogWrite(MotorSpeed, motorValue); 
 delay(100);      
  }
 }
}
```

for some reason i cant figure out how to get MotorDirection and MotorDirection2 even as MotorSpeed and MotorSpeed2 to work at the same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code never writes the second motor speed.  Have you tried adding the line:

```
analogWrite(MotorSpeed2, motorValue);
```

below each line with MotorSpeed1?

I'm also confused by the extra {} braces throughout your code.

Comment: the extra {} are becouse in this line:  {
 analogWrite(MotorSpeed, motorValue); 
 delay(100);      
  } this needs to be set as 1 line

Comment: but thanks it works now i treid to get it in the same line as MotorSpeed1 and didn't think about putting it in the next line

Comment: Thanks for explaining the {}.  I've never written code for an Arduino.

Comment: no problem if you are going to use arduino some time and you are getting errows always check the {} couse they can couse so much trouble if placedwrong or not at all